# Is there a method in python for randomly selected a subset of tuples with weighting and no replacement?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples that I want to randomly choose a subset from, but using weights to affect how likely an element is to be chosen and that doesn't use replacement.

I've tried random.choices(), which handles the subset and the weights element, but it uses replacement so I'm getting the same element repeatedly in the subset. For example, if my large set is [red (10&),orange (10%),blue(10%),yellow(10%),green(50%)], and I want a subset of 3 of them, random.choices often results in [green,green,blue].

I've also looked at random.sample(), which doesn't use replacement but doesn't allow for weighting, and at numpy.random.choice(), which requires a 1D array (which a list of tuples is not).

Is there another method I should be looking at?

Comment: You can set `replace=False` in `numpy.random.choice()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with numpy

```
 from numpy.random import choice

 list_len = len(tuple_list)
 np_list = np.arange(list_len)
 draw = choice(np_list, number_of_items_to_pick, p=list_prob, replace=False)
 selected = []
 for n in draw:
     selected.append(tuple_list[n])
```

this will choose the tuples without replacement by setting `replace=False` with `tuple_list` being your list of tuples, and `list_prob` being their probabilities of being chosen. Creating a list of indexes with `np.arange(list_len)` allows you to get around the two dimensional issue by randomly selecting the indexes of the tuples you want rather than the tuples directly.

Comment: The solution doesn't work when the ````tuple_list```` contains tuples as ````numpy```` assumes the list to be two-dimensional

Comment: @Advay168 i added a work around to fix that issue :)